# Angular not working on ie8 despite recommandations

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create an angularjs app which would be used on ie8.

According to this page : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie it should work with angular 1.2, which I use.

My index.html is :

```
<!doctyme html>
<html ng-app="app" id="ng-app" >
<head>
    <script src="./angular.js">
    </script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./custom.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="statsController">
    <label>Nom:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}</h1>

        <div>
    <label>Seance:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourSession" placeholder="Entersession name">
    <hr>
    <h1>Vous voulez des stats pour {{ yourSession }}</h1>
    </div>

    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="seance in seances | filter:yourSession">
    <td> {{seance.title}} </td>
    <td> {{seance.stats }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js code is

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('statsController', function($scope){
    $scope.seances = [
        {"id":1 , "title":"seance1 ,multi-acces", "stats":150},
        {"id":2 , "title":"seance 2  ,etre administrateur", "stats":550},
        {"id":3 , "title":"seance3, comment gérer sa vie", "stats":10},
        {"id":4 , "title":"derniere seance , comment réussir son breakfast", "stats":15150}
        ];
    $scope.yourName = "lzlz";
        });
```

The problem is that my browser does not interprate the {{yourName}} and displays it as is.

Does someone know why it doesnt work?

Thanks

Comment: But everything else works? Any errors in the dev-tools console?

Comment: You've got angular.js and custom.js in the html. Do you have the source for both these files? If your angular.js file contains the js posted above you need to include it below the angular source cdn files

Comment: you also have a typo in doctype (doctyme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment to answer:

you have a typo in doctype (doctyme)

Answer (score 0):

Lee Willis was right (in the comment of my question),

my typo (Doctyme instead of doctype) is the source of the problem (even though it works on firefox).

Now it's corrected, it works and I'm ashamed .

It even seems to work with angular 1.3

Thanks for the help Lee Willis